# HLS streams with ac3 audio not working on chromecast

Tags: video-streaming, chromecast, aac, http-live-streaming

Chromecast doesn't stream videos which have ac3 audio. only streams that have the aac codec are working. is there a way to achieve ac3 audio stream support on chromecast while using hls? 
The sample HLS streams tested

1. AC3 https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ht-brightcove/Dar_20/AC3/playlist.m3u8
2. AAC 
   https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ht-brightcove/Dar_20/5AAC/playlist.m3u8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Chromecast can not decode ac3. https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

Comment: I checked the link. It says that it supports AC3 passthrough

Comment: Correct. Pass through without decoding. So what ever the chromecast is plugged into must support ac3 decoding. Most Tvs do not.

Comment: Thanks!. I guess we'll have to make do with AAC now.